# Displaying the search data in database MySQL

Tags: php

How can I display the data that I search in the MySQL?

I tried this code but it always give me an error of :

> "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\FindFriend\resultFindFriend.php on line 12"

```
<?php

if(!isset($_POST['dataFriend'])){
    echo("no result");

}else {

    $find = $_POST['dataFriend'];
    $con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','','test');
    $queryFindFriend = "SELECT fullname FROM members WHERE fullname LIKE '%".$find."%'";
    $friendResult = mysqli_query($con, $queryFindFriend);
    $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($friendResult);
    foreach($rows as $row)
    {
    ?>
        <div class="outputfindfriend">
        <?php echo $row;?>
        </div>
    <?php
    }   
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused because [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) fetches a single row at the time. And thus, `$rows` is not an array but a simple value.

With a more recent PHP 5.4+ version you can just use `foreach` on the mysqli result:

```
foreach ($friendResult as $row): ?>
    <div class="outputfindfriend">
    <?= $row['fullname'] ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach;
```

The foreach will do one row at a time.

If you've got a PHP version lower than PHP 5.4 this is not possible this way.

To solve this problem you have to change the logic of the loop. We can use the fact that `mysqli_fetch_assoc` will return false when there are no more row. So we can change the `for` to a `while` with an assignment statement in it. This way, it'll will output until `$row` is assigned false.

Do something like this :

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($friendResult))
{
?>
    <div class="outputfindfriend">
    <?php echo $row;?>
    </div>
<?php
}
```

This way, you fetch a row, then output it and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<?php echo $row['your field name'];?>
```

Comment: it didnt work i tried echo $row['fullname']

Comment: for show all of a array items use: $print_r($row); that show array with all of keys & values, this help you to see your array has this key or no